# Which version of android studio is suitable for windows 7 32 bit 2gb ram?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, intellij-idea, netbeans

I've searched version of Android Studio for windows 7 32 bit with 2gb ram but I couldn't find it. I can't go to android studio's main site.
Of course, I couldn't find it and tried to find InteliJ IDEA but it also is not applicable for my pc. Now I have got just Netbeans IDE version 8.
Now I wanna to have the suitable version of android studio for android development.
Please Help.

Comment: It would be hard to develop Android apps on this hardware. I'd recommend upgrading. Even if you can run some old Android Studio or IntelliJ IDEA version on it, it will work extremely slow and will be not compatible with the recent Android tools and emulators.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7/8/10 (32-bit or 64-bit)

3 GB RAM minimum, 8 GB RAM recommended (plus 1 GB for the Android Emulator)

2 GB of available disk space minimum, 4 GB recommended (500 MB for IDE plus 1.5 GB for Android SDK and emulator system image)

1280 x 800 minimum screen resolution.

Check  this for details https://www.infoworld.com/article/3095406/android-studio-for-beginners-part-1-installation-and-setup.html

Comment: This does not answer the question. It asks _"**Which version of android studio** is suitable for windows 7 32 bit 2gb ram?"_, but your answer just lists hardware requirements.